# How to Implement Connection Pool in HttpSolrClient?

Tags: solrj, solrclient

I want to implement Connection Pooling in SolrClient using java. Not getting right doc. Some one please help

rigth now I am trying as below

`SolrClient Solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrlString + solrCoreName).build();`